# How to place ionic tabs at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: tabs, ionic-framework

I created a simple ionic-tabs that shows my icons at the top of the screen. I tried to wrap it in a ionic-footer-bar in order to have it placed at the bottom of the screen with no success. The tabs disappear when I do that. How should I accomplish the looks I want?

```
<ion-footer-bar>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only tabs-stable">
    ...
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Answer (score 175):

Since the **beta 14** of Ionic (http://blog.ionic.io/the-final-beta/), there are some config variables that now default to their platform values, which means that they will try to behave according to the platform that they are built on.
In the case of tabs, for iOS the default is to display on bottom, and Android on top.

You can easily "hard set" the location for all platforms by setting the `tabs.position` function in the `$ionicConfigProvider`, inside your config function like this:

```
MyApp.config(['$ionicConfigProvider', function($ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // other values: top

}]);
```

You can check documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/%24ionicConfigProvider/)

Comment: no it doesn't work. On the browser tabs are at the bottom, on Android - on top

Comment: @Toolkit Android tabs are supposed to be rendered on top by default according to Ionic docs. Android guidelines are to avoid using bottom bars  because of the OS default actions located at the bottom: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: @Toolkit I've already edited the answer to fix the platform defaults information. If you want to customise it, the code above is the right way to it. However I would suggest you to avoid changing platform defaults, they tend to follow the platform guidelines. =)

Comment: Is there a way, using this method or another, to have bottom and top tabs? I tried creating another state for my footer but, for some reason, it's not rendering to the screen even though i see it in the network tab in my browser. Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Answer (score 65):

To place the ionicFramework tabs at the bottom of the screen for android devices just open your **app.js** file, and under **angular.module** add the following lines of code:

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
})
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: How to achieve tabs on both top and bottom of the screen?

Comment: I think you could create separate template for tabs on bottom and top

Comment: Oh yes. I get it. I'm a newbie in this ionic's world.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. It's simple and straight to the point, you got my up-vote...

Comment: While set android tab to bottom it's working well as per your code, But while pressing keyboard the tab as well showing up with the tab. Is there any option to set it stable in the bottom while pressing keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

Update for Ionic 2 (cleaner/improved syntax):

In app.js:

```
@App({
  ...
  config: {
    tabbarPlacement: 'bottom',
  }
})
```

[See Configs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/)

Answer (score 7):

Placing it in your app.js does the work.

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
})
```

Ionic automatically takes platform configurations into account to adjust things like what transition style to use and whether tab icons should show on the top or bottom.

For example, In the case of tabs, for iOS the default is to display on bottom, and Android on top.

***Note1*** : **It should be noted that when a platform is not iOS or Android, then it’ll default to iOS**

***Note2*** **:** **if you are developing on a desktop browser, it’s going to take on iOS default configs**

Answer (score 5):

In side the app.js file you will need to inject the  $ionicConfigProvider to the .config module and add **$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position(‘bottom’)**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {

 $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); //top

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
.
.
.
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

Answer (score 3):

## How to place ionic tabs at the bottom of the screen in Ionic 2

For the current version ionic 2.0.0-beta.10.

In app.ts:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {
  tabbarPlacement: "bottom"
});
```

See [Config](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.10/api/config/Config/)

For the soon to be released ionic 2.0.0-beta.11

In app.ts:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {
  tabsPlacement: "bottom" 
});
```

[Config](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/)

Answer (score 2):

```
myapp.config(['$ionicConfigProvider', function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // other values: top
}]);
```

Comment: Please, avoid code only answers and explain your solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Update for Ionic 2, and Ionic 3+:

You have 2 methods to change tab bar position:

**Method 1: Use `tabsPlacement` propertive of `<ion-tabs>`**

```
<ion-tabs  tabsPlacement='bottom' >
    <ion-tab [root]="rootTab" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab> 
</ion-tabs>
```

**Method 2: Change config in `app.module.ts`**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      tabsPlacement : 'bottom'
    })
  ]
})
```

See the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/)

Comment: Is there anything remotely similar for the Segment component? I can put it at the bottom with CSS no worries, but putting the border on the buttons on top then sort of has so many loops to jump through and feels rather hacky, so I wonder if there was an easier solution, but came across none in the docs. Actually, the Segment doc is rather short....https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/

Comment: Answer to self: `ion-segment-button.segment-button {
border-top-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 0;
}` does the trick, however, for the border-top-width I didn't find any other recourse than to set it explicitly in the style-attribute on the element to 2px. Something else always overwrites it with 3px, even setting it in Chrome on the element and with !important in the style sheet does not seem to top that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<ion-footer><ion-tabs> <ion-tab tabTitle="Return"></ion-tab>  </ion-tabs></ion-footer>`