# Cordova compiles android different than ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am kind of new to Cordova + Ionic. I try to compile an example ([Codepen Example][1])
I see that it is compiled for IOS properly but not for android.

What could be wrong for android?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BHqx.jpg

http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA`

```
<title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(user)">
          Sign-In
        </button>
        <p class="text-center">
          <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/forgot-password.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Forgot Password">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <p>
        Yeah this is just a demo showing how views can be shown without tabs, then you can navigate
        to views within tabs. Additionally, only one set of tabs needs to be written for all of the different views that should go inside the tabs. (Compared to written the same tab links in the footer of every view that's in a tab.)
      </p>
      <p>
        There's no username/password, just click
        the Sign-In button back a the sign-in view.
      </p>
      <p>
        Return to <a href="#/sign-in">Sign-In</a>.
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Sign-Out" icon="ion-log-out" href="#/sign-in">
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
      navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
      each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Facts">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
      <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
      <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
      <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
      <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script> 

<script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
      <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
      <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
      <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
      <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
      <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="About">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
      <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
      <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between iOS and Android are some differents.

this solves your title align-left problem:

add the class "title-center" to your ion-view

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-controller="homeCtrl" class="title-center">
```

This solves your tabs-problem:
found here: [android tabs bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874855/how-to-place-ionic-tabs-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

> You can easily "hard set" the location for all platforms by setting
>   the tabs.position function in the $ionicConfigProvider, inside your
>   config function like this:
>
> ```
> MyApp.config(['$ionicConfigProvider', function($ionicConfigProvider) {
>
>     $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // other values: top
>
> }]);
> ```
>
> You can check documentation here:
>   http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/%24ionicConfigProvider/

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about the buttons? Buttons show differently too.. Is it because there is font scale difference?

Comment: Do you mean that in Android the texts are breaked?

Comment: Yes, exactly, Buttons doesn't look like as it intented to

Comment: sorry in this point i cant help you, i would try to define some css rules only for android like: word-break

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any documents that which elements compile different in android and ios? I can't know that until I compile for android.

Comment: I am working with this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/platform-customization/ and i cant find some good documents that could help you before compile. Just compile it and find the differences and then just change the css for the Platform :)